# How do I add two new columns on the basis of the values of multiple other columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add two columns to an existing dataframe based on the values of a few other columns. My dataframe looks like this:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','',''], 'Type1':['A', 'A', '', 'B','',''], 'Type2':['A','B','B','B','A',''], 'Score':[1, 2, 3, 1, 0 ,0], 'Score1':[2, 1, 0, 1, 0 ,0], 'Score2':[1, 3, 2, 1, 2 ,0]})`

```
  Type  Type1   Type2   Score   Score1  Score2
0   A     A       A        1       2      1
1   A     A       B        2       1      3
2   A             B        3       0      2
3   B     B       B        1       1      1
4                 A        0       0      2
5                          0       0      0
```

I want to add two columns 'Score_A' and 'Score_B' such that 'Score_A' will be the mean of scores
for cases where Type is 'A' (for each row). Likewise for 'Score_B'. A catch is that wherever the Type is blank, the score should not be used to calculate the mean.

The result of a successful function, in this case, will be:

```
Score_A  Score_B
  1.33      0 
  1.5       3
   3        2
   0        1
   2        0
   0        0
```

I have run nested loops at a row level to do this, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m1 = (df[['Type', 'Type1', 'Type2']] == 'A')
m2 = (df[['Type', 'Type1', 'Type2']] == 'B')
scores = df[['Score', 'Score1', 'Score2']]

df['Score_A'] = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m1, scores, np.nan)).mean(skipna=True, axis=1).fillna(0)
df['Score_B'] = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m2, scores, np.nan)).mean(skipna=True, axis=1).fillna(0)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Type Type1 Type2  Score  Score1  Score2   Score_A  Score_B
0    A     A     A      1       2       1  1.333333      0.0
1    A     A     B      2       1       3  1.500000      3.0
2    A           B      3       0       2  3.000000      2.0
3    B     B     B      1       1       1  0.000000      1.0
4                A      0       0       2  2.000000      0.0
5                       0       0       0  0.000000      0.0
```